my texture gets messy
im very new to blender and i completely dont know what is going on 
i am not sure if you can see the weird yellow deck texture on the conning tower. but i think its the problem with tthe texture being pixelated and it spills over the other uv faces
i dont really know how to fix the issue

If you would go to the UV Editor instead of the Image Editor, you could see where the UV of one face ends and another begins... edit the UVs so that they do not get colored where they are not supposed to. And if what we are seeing there is how the end result should be (i.e. plain colors limited to specific faces), you could simply have a grey material and a yellow material, then select the faces which should be yellow and assign the material to them. And if you have no idea how to do this I would highly recommend you watch some beginner tutorials on materials, UV mapping, texturing etc.

If you are texture painting the yellow into the image, try using Face Select Masking in the top bar right next to the Mode dropdown that says 'Texture Paint' - click the little square there and then you can use select tool to pick what faces to paint and then use Draw tool to paint them. Also, as mentioned your UV islands might be too close together or in fact your Bleed in Options might be set to something larger than 2 pixels.

thanks it really worked

btw island margin also work but it destroys my resolution
